# What text encoding is used in "Zip archive data, at least v?[0x314] to extract"?

Tags: bash, zip, encoding, character-encoding

I tried multiple search terms on the usual suspect search engines as well as on stack overflow and superuser, but can't find anything on this. Normally a Zip archive magic pattern is "at least v1.0" or "at least v2.0".

The closest I can come is "COMBINING REVERSED COMMA ABOVE" or "Greek dasia, rough breathing mark" which appears to me as a curly single open quote, but it makes no sense in the context, so I doubt it's right.

No issues with the zip archive, just a curiosity.

If it helps the string was generated by file v5.33 on macOS 10.14 with bash 4.4.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that the `file` command doesn't have definitions that understand what version zip file you have.

The [zip definition](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/zip) for `file` has a section

```
# Zip known versions
0   name        zipversion
>0  leshort     0x09        v0.9
>0  leshort     0x0a        v1.0
>0  leshort     0x0b        v1.1
>0  leshort     0x14        v2.0
>0  leshort     0x15        v2.1
>0  leshort     0x19        v2.5
>0  leshort     0x1b        v2.7
>0  leshort     0x2d        v4.5
>0  leshort     0x2e        v4.6
>0  leshort     0x32        v5.0
>0  leshort     0x33        v5.1
>0  leshort     0x34        v5.2
>0  leshort     0x3d        v6.1
>0  leshort     0x3e        v6.2
>0  leshort     0x3f        v6.3
>0  default     x
>>0 leshort x v?[%#x]
```

And it basically means that `file` fell out the end of that definition list and is just telling you the zip version number needed to extract it.

It looks like that list may need updating. There have been a [few changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Version_history) since 6.3. It is possible that the magic bytes listed are for 6.3.5 but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at it entirely wrong. Thank you!